# Slider not changing a value when clicked?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm creating a simple drawpad in python using tkinter and python 3.

I have a slider at the bottom of it that lets me change the size of the dot that is created, however when I change the slider it does not execute the expected sub-routine.

How can I correct this?

```
DotSize=0
Scale = Scale(Buttons, from_=1, to=100, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=250, command=Size, highlightcolor="Red")
Scale.grid(row=1, column=7)

def Size():
    global DotSize
    DotSize=Scale.get()
```

Dotsize changes this:

```
def draw(event):
    global DotSize
    Canvas.create_oval(event.x, event.y,event.x,event.y, fill="black", width=DotSize)
```

At the moment I am having to use a button to execute `Size()` but that's just ugly and counter intuitive.

Comment: This code can't possibly work because you're referencing `Size` before you define it. Also, how do you know that Dotsize isn't being called? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ok my bad on formatting. The Scale stuff is actually under the def Size(): code but i copy + pasted differnt parts because there is more code than that.

Comment: And what do you mean by "DotSize is being called"? I know it isnt taking the value 0 because i can change the size of the dot created.

Comment: that was a typo. I meant "how do you know `Size` isn't being called?

Comment: I just checked by adding a print("xyz") line of code and it printed nothing, until i clicked the button to force it to change the size of the dot.

Comment: Without seeing _actual_ code that produces the problem, there's nothing we can do. I will say, however, that if you hook it up properly to the function you'll get an error. The scale sends an argument to the command, which your function isn't prepared to accept.

Comment: I think `Size()` has been executed when you move the slider, but exception generated due to missing argument.  Change `def Size()` to `def Size(value)` where `value` is the current slider value.  Actually, `Size()` is not necessary and you can get the slider value directly in the `draw(...)` function and use that value to draw the oval.